# CruiseControl + Starteam: not picking up all files

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net, starteam

Our CruiseControl system checks out from starteam. I've noticed that it is sometimes not checking out new versions of files, only added files.

Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot say *why* this happens, but for what it's worth, we avoid the problem entirely by having StarTeam delete all of the local files before checking-out. We get *all* of the files that way. We use the following StarTeam arguments in our NAnt script:

```
delete-local -q -p &quot;${starteam_project_root}&quot; -is -filter &quot;N&quot; -cfgd &quot;${exec_time}&quot;
```

Which translates to something like:

```
delete-local -q -p "user:passwd@SERVER:49201/ProjectName/" -is -filter "N"-cfgd "09/18/2008 14:33:22"
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into this same issue.  The reason this happens is the same reason you don't see out of date files in the GUI or you have a file with unknown status, the status is not updated.  So if you update the status on your files it will then be able to pick up those files that have changed from the source control.  We accomplish this by adding a  step to our configuration file.

```
  <prebuild>
    <exec>
      <executable>C:\Program Files\Borland\StarTeam Cross-Platform Client 2006 R2\stcmd.exe</executable >
      <buildArgs>update-status -nologo -is -q -p "username:password@192.168.0.1:49201/Code Project/Code Path" -fp "C:\projects\My Code Directory"</buildArgs>
      <buildTimeoutSeconds>0</buildTimeoutSeconds>
    </exec>
  </prebuild>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a CI build, so I want to see the diffs on each build, cleaning out the build gives me a fresh build each time, and I don't know what is new.

So its a known issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the StarTeam Ant task, check to see what you have set for the **includes** and **excludes** parameters to make sure you are not unintentionally restricting what gets checked out.

Also the **forced** and **recursive** parameters may be something to look at as well.

You can see a full explanation of the checkout task here:

http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/help/tasks/stcheckout.html